# SQL Fetch rows if it satisfies all criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have here a table for schedule of 2 employees. How will I retrieve the rows of a certain employee which has a complete schedule from **monday** to **sunday** and starts from **2016-08-15** upto **2016-08-21**

```
| id | emp_id |    date    | day |
|----|--------|------------|-----|
| 1  |  emp1  | 2016-08-17 | Wed |
| 2  |  emp1  | 2016-08-18 | Thu |
| 3  |  emp1  | 2016-08-19 | Fri |
| 4  |  emp1  | 2016-08-20 | Sat |
| 5  |  emp1  | 2016-08-21 | Sun |
| 6  |  emp2  | 2016-08-15 | Mon |
| 7  |  emp2  | 2016-08-16 | Tue |
| 8  |  emp2  | 2016-08-17 | Wed |
| 9  |  emp2  | 2016-08-18 | Thu |
| 10 |  emp2  | 2016-08-19 | Fri |
| 11 |  emp2  | 2016-08-20 | Sat |
| 12 |  emp2  | 2016-08-21 | Sun |
```

So basically it should retrieve only the entries of emp 2. This is how the output should be

```
| 6  |  emp2  | 2016-08-15 | Mon |
| 7  |  emp2  | 2016-08-16 | Tue |
| 8  |  emp2  | 2016-08-17 | Wed |
| 9  |  emp2  | 2016-08-18 | Thu |
| 10 |  emp2  | 2016-08-19 | Fri |
| 11 |  emp2  | 2016-08-20 | Sat |
| 12 |  emp2  | 2016-08-21 | Sun |
```

But if emp1 has monday and tuesday sched it should also be retrieved.

**UPDATED**

Actually I'm applying this in codeigniter and with the help of the answers I've managed to translate it into a codeigniter active record syntax and this is how my code looks like:

```
$schedule = $this->db->query("SELECT *
                FROM schedule
                LEFT JOIN employees
                ON employees.user_id = schedule.user_id;
                WHERE schedule.user_id IN (SELECT user_id
                                   FROM schedule
                                   WHERE start >= '2016-08-15' and start <= '2016-08-21'
                                   group by user_id
                                   having count(*) = 7
                                  ); ");


if($schedule->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $schedule->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

By the way I also have another table that needs to be joined with the schedule table. But this seems to be in an incorrect way because I got an error. How should I resolve this?

Comment: Please specify whether you want all entries of emp2 or only those within the given date range.

Comment: I only need the the entries of emp2 within the given date range

Comment: It was quite a good question before the update. So i suggest you to: - Roll back your update - Upvote both answers - Accept Mureiniks answer - Learn to debug your code - Delete the `;` in your ON-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a full schedule from `2016-08-15` to `2016-08-21` means having seven days scheduled. So you could just check the number of days scheduled in this timeframe and make sure you have seven (different) ones:

```
SELECT *
FROM   schedule
WHERE  `date` >= '2016-08-15' AND 
       `date` <= '2016-08-21' AND
       emp_id IN (SELECT   emp_id
                  FROM     schedule
                  WHERE    `date` >= '2016-08-15' AND `date` <= '2016-08-21'
                  GROUP BY emp_id
                  HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT `date) = 7)
```

Comment: @Murenik Thank you :) I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select emp_id
from t
where date >= '2016-08-15' and date <= '2016-08-21'
group by emp_id
having count(*) = 7;
```

To get the detailed records, you can use a `join`, `in`, or `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.emp_id in (select emp_id
                   from t
                   where date >= '2016-08-15' and date <= '2016-08-21'
                   group by emp_id
                   having count(*) = 7
                  );
```